# Is it possible to retrieve all records from only one BigQuery table cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

BigQuery's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) says the following about clustered tables:

> When you create a clustered table in BigQuery, the table data is automatically organized based on the contents of one or more columns in the table’s schema. **The columns you specify are used to colocate related data.** When you cluster a table using multiple columns, the order of columns you specify is important. **The order of the specified columns determines the sort order of the data.**

Since the records in the table are already colocated and sorted, is it possible to retrieve all the records from an arbitrary cluster?

I have a table that is too large to use `ORDER BY`. However, it is already clustered in the manner I need, so I can save a lot of time and expense if I could retrieve all the data from each cluster separately.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer besides querying using the clustered field?  If your table is clustered on `color` for example, `select * from table where color = 'red'`

Comment: @rtenha, yes I am looking for an answer besides filtering on the clustered fields. I need to send all the data from the table to a batch processing job downstream.

Comment: Will clustering help to speed up query and reduce cost? Yes. Will clustering replace the need to "ORDER BY"? No.

Comment: If you aren't looking to query the data from BQ, then it might make more sense to add google-cloud tags to this post.  From a BQ perspective, I would loop through all values of your clustered column (`red`, `blue`, `green`, etc ), querying and exporting each cluster.

Comment: Thanks, I've added additional tags. I have not been able to find any approaches in BigQuery that eliminate the need for `ORDER BY`, so I am beginning to suspect @YunZhang is right.

Comment: Looping through all the values in my clustered columns is not feasible either. I have thousands of distinct values, and the query for each value is fast and cheap--however, the thousands of queries required to get the whole dataset is many times more expensive than the whole dataset. I have also experimented with looping through chunks of distinct values (e.g. Query 1 would get `('red', 'blue')`, Query 2 would get `('green', 'yellow')`, etc. However, because I cannot tell which values are located in which cluster, each of my chunked queries ends up scanning most of the clusters.

Comment: looks to me that while you have some practical goal / task to achieve and you are have idea of how to address it - the question is still around the idea, which potentially not the good/best idea at all. so I would rather focus on what your real target, what it is that you are trying to achieve - this would give us more room for helping you. just a suggestion

Comment: Why do you need to order the result ? Most of time is for having the top 10, 100 of something.